# If $X$ is homeomorphic to a Lie group, is $X$ is a manifold?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lie-groups

The question is pretty straight-forward, but I have been unable to find an answer:

*Let $G$ be a (compact Hausdorff) Lie group. If $X$ is homeomorphic to $G$ as a topological space, is $X$ then also a topological manifold?*

Comment: What did you try? I suggest, start by writing down the definition of a Lie group; no need to assume compactness.

Comment: This question can be generalised as follows: "If $Y$ is a topological manifold, and $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, is $X$ also a topological manifold?", or more precisely, "can $X$ be given the structure of a topological manifold?" The answer is yes. It has nothing particular to do with the Lie group structure (or compactness, as Moishe said).

Comment: Thanks, I see it now. Pretty trivial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this fully answers the question, but might point in some useful direction.  Per wikipedia:
"Two spaces with a homeomorphism between them are called homeomorphic, and **from a topological viewpoint they are the same.**"  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)

and then from the definition of a Lie group:
"Lie groups, named after Sophus Lie, are differentiable **manifolds** that ..." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold).

Combining these two pieces of information seems to suggest that $X$ is indeed a manifold.

I hope this helps.